# In hadoop Map-Reduce, how to know end of map task or end of filesplit

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

A map task in hadoop works on a 64/128 MB split of the input file. It starts processing from the 1st line of the input split till the end. I need to find out how to know when a map task is done processing its input split. In other words, before shuffle and sort begins. Is there any method in hadoop library which can answer my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cleanup` method of the `Mapper` class allows you to execute code when the mapper is done processing the input split, simply override it in the same way you override the `map` method.

If that's not what you're after, maybe a `Counter` can solve your problem?